# Logback 1.2.3 logs being cut off mid-line

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, vert.x

I am building a data crawler in Java. Here are some info:
Project: Gradle.
Framework: Vert.x 4.0.3.
Logback version: 1.2.3.
slf4j version: 1.7.30.
Using Lombok
MacBook Pro 15" mid 2014.
Big Sur v 11.2.3.
Storage about 50% free.
Memory about 50% free in use.
Java version: Java 11.

My application is set so that HTTP GET requests are repeatedly called - ideally forever.
And all the logs are logged to the terminal/console and also on the log file generated by logback.xml.
If I run my application overnight, then a log is cut off mid-line.
After the cut line, there is no log even though the terminal/console has all the logs.

Here is my logback.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" debug="true">

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%-4relative) --- [ %thread{10} ] %cyan(%logger{20}) : %msg%n </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<!--    <file>/var/log/crawler/crawler.log</file>-->
    <file>crawler.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<!--      <fileNamePattern>/var/log/crawler/crawler-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>-->
      <fileNamePattern>crawler-%d.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %-4relative --- [ %thread{10} ] %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="io.netty" level="warn"/>
  <logger name="io.vertx" level="info"/>
  <logger name="com.hazelcast" level="info"/>
  <logger name="kr.co.evcloud.crawler" level="debug"/> <!-- 개발중에 편하게 쓰려고 변경하였습니다. -->

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> <!-- Console에 로그를 출력하고자 할 때 사용 -->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> <!-- File로 로그를 남기고자 할 때 사용 -->
  </root>
</configuration>
```

The logback uses `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, which on midnight, pushes all current logs to a new log file with the previous date.

On two occasions, the following log was left.

```
2021-05-27 00:13:49.019 DEBUG 14038900 --- [ vert.x-eventloop-thread-1 ] k.c.e.crawler.service.MeDataService - ### [환경부 API] charger_id: 200949 새 상태: 2, 이전 상태: 9
2021-05-27 00:13:49.019 DEBUG 14038900 --- [ vert.x-eventloop-thread-1 ] k.c.e.crawler.service.MeDataService - ### [환경부 API] charger_id: 200958 새 상태: 2, 이전 상태: 9
2021-05-27 00:13:49.020 DEBUG 1403
```

There are three logs above: 2 of which are complete, one of which is cut off.
And even though my terminal has all the logs since 00:13:49 til now, the log file is not being updated.

Any guesses as to why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention what I've tried. I ran my application and changed the dates and times on my laptop. I ran the application in three ways: one with Intellij run, one with the fat jar in IntelliJ terminal, and one with the fat jar in terminal. While changing laptop dates and times, there were no logs cut off. So I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-211.7142.45, built on April 30, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.41 x86_64
```

When I opened the log files with cut lines in VSCode, all the logs showed.
IntelliJ seems show only part of large .log files.

If anyone stumbles on not seeing your logs or cut off lines of logs, try opening the file in different IDE or program.